# Converting .ui to .py

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create my very first gui via Pyqt 5, and python 3.6

I created the interface in Qt designer ,got needed .ui file and now want to translate it to .py. I found that it could be done with pyui5, but can't find how.

Used this to start .ui through python:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = loadUi('D:\test.ui')
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I can't change anything in code,so transformation from .ui to .py is needed. 
Pyuic5 command in cmd is not working.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem. I installed pyqt via pip, after that found pyuic5.bat in Library/Bin folder. Then transformed with it .ui to .py

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pyuic4` command:
`pyuic4 input.ui -o output.py`

Comment: I can't find pyuic4.exe file to launch it. Searched in whole pyqt5 archive-and nothing

Comment: you have to download it @Acapulka

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/ @Acapulka

Comment: I did it, but still cant find pyuic4.bat or exe in archive

Comment: there is no archive, you can directly download the binary file @Acapulka

Comment: Got it, I didn't know that I should install pyqt 4.11 to get that file. Thank you,will try to transform now

Comment: Seems like it trying to launch python 3.4, and giving error: "C:\Python34\python"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."< but what I have is python 3.6.2, so mb I will just rewrite pyuic4.bat and put location of my python.exe ?

Comment: nope. seems like I didn't configure pyqt, so I decided to do it as in manual. I started python configure.py, and it gave me next error:Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
C:\Users\MadRobot\Anaconda3\Library\bin\qmake.exe -o cfgtest_QtCore.mk cfgtest_QtCore.pro
nmake -f cfgtest_QtCore.mk release
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: "Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem."

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Application to convert the .ui (Pyqt5 Created by qt designer) file to py.

you can convert your file easily using this application
Direct Download Link: https://download1653.mediafire.com/utmxc4pza7ug/1f0gkwk6577g7fi/Ui+to+Py.zip

Mediafire link to download: https://www.mediafire.com/file/1f0gkwk6577g7fi/Ui_to_Py.zip/file

you check the source code of the application on my GitHub: https://github.com/Harvindar994/

Comment: Direct downloading zip files here is _okay_ I suppose, but it would be a good idea to link directly to the source code rather than the github user, provide options to build from source if possible, and provide some instructions on usage.